# Rails + Devise Login flash message wrongly showing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rubygems

When I sighed in, it's showing "Successfully logged out." flash message. But it has to show "successfully logged in" as per devise gem.

I am using,
 ruby 2.2.2
 rails 4.2.0
 devise 3.5.5

This is the existed code:

```
# In my config/locales/devise.en.yml
sessions:
  new:
    confirm_button: "Sign in"
    title: "Sign in"
  signed_in: "Signed in successfully."
  signed_out: "Signed out successfully."

# In my config/locales/devise.de.yml
sessions:
  new:
    confirm_button: "Login"
    title: "Login"
  signed_in: Erfolgreich angemeldet.
  signed_out: Erfolgreich abgemeldet.
```

How to fix this ? There is any config in devise.rb

Comment: please add more details. What should be showed? why it is an issue?

Comment: sorry, I am new for stack.. Now i added some more notes.

Comment: Can you show your sessions controller please

Comment: `class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  layout 'stubs'
end`

Comment: AM i missing any configuration in devise.rb

Comment: You may have added the `signed_in` key more than once.